# Apache and letsencrypt ssl | need assistance from cloudflare gurus or experts in ssl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lets-encrypt, cloudflare

hope you are all staying well and safe.

So just to explain my setup which I have always proffered do which worked for me, until now..

I have:

- Ubuntu server running apache2 for websites
- Letsencrypt via certbot (installed last week along with fresh ubuntu server)
- Cloudflare linked

With this I am able to host my multiple sites and provide free ssl to them (letsencrypt) via running the command: `sudo certbot --apache`.
**Next** I will add the domain to cloudflare for one singular reason - I use their proxy DNS 
by clicking the orange cloud on the DNS page. I go via cloudflare for one reason, to hide the ip of the site where the server sits, it is just a nice handy feature and I see it help fight attacks more.

This all used to work well with no problem and the ssl would be served by letsencrypt.
However now when I try todo the both it creates problems and displays the ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH browser message when you try to load the site. I noticed there is a SSL mode which you can alter and also 'Edge certificates' which for some reason it is trying to make.

My question is, how would I go about making the changes so that Cloudflare lets Letsencrypt deliver the ssl but uses the proxy feature to hide the IP - since I may have to turn OFF the ssl mode? Will this problem be fixed if i turn the SSL mode in cloudflare to off? But then will that cause issues with it taking it to the https website through letsencrypt/certbot?
When it has worked in the past and I clicked the padlock button on the browser I saw it had the certificate issued to cloudflaressl.com.

Thank you guys, I hope someone can shed some light.

Comment: Does this article help you: [Validating a Let’s Encrypt Certificate on a Site Already Active on Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/214820528-Validating-a-Let-s-Encrypt-Certificate-on-a-Site-Already-Active-on-Cloudflare).

Answer (score 0):

When your origin server has proper SSL certificate (for example Letsencrypt), you need to use Cloudflare's Full (strict) in the SSL/TLS / Overview page.

Your edge certificates need to match the domains used in your server.

Also, to properly allow Certbot to validate domains, you need to have either:

A) "Always use HTTPS" off in SSL/TLS / Edge certificates page
B) "Always use HTTPS" on in SSL/TLS / Edge certificates page and a rule in "Rules" section, where "www.example.com/.well-known/*" location has Automatic HTTPS rewrites switched off.

Comment: THose already are my settings, it is currently turned on 'full'